# Powering a ESP8226 via supplied breakout board

Tags: esp8266

I have brought a couple of ESP8226s from ebay to have a go at making some fancy wi-fi controlled projects and i'm having some trouble, i cant get anything out of them!
With the chips I got breakout boards, (see pictures), i have dutifully soldered them up so i can put everything on a breadboard. When i plug it into my 3.3v power supply i don't get anything (the onboard LED does nothing and i don't get any response via serial).

Putting a meter on it I don't have any connection between the VCC of the breakout and the VCC of the chip.

Has anyone use one of these boards before? There are 3 small holes that could be needing a component/jumper in them but i have no idea what and don't want to start soldering stuff willy-nilly. What do i need to do to get my chips powered?

Thanks

[image: Top of Breakout]

Comment: I think you're better off asking the supplier than us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These breakout boards are meant to be used with a 3v3 linear LDO regulator, for which there is a place at the backside of the PCB. This makes it possible to power the board with 5V (from for instance USB).

If you have 3.3V available (note: with sufficient current: the 3.3V output of for instance a usb-serial converter won't work!) you can replace the regulator by a short of the two copper fields at the back nearest to the Vcc side (the 3d copper field is conected to the GND).

Comment: Thats it! As i already have a 3.3v powers supply with more than enough current i have just shorted the two pads; put power on and get blue lights! Thanks very much